# NodeJs Convert 'net' socket to SSL/TLS based socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl

I have following nodejs code running on the server (chat engine). I want to convert this into a secure SSL/TLS based connection. How do i do that ?

In the client side (see below code), everytime i tried to convert this into SSL it gives me a error of "Cross origin request failed." i dont know why ?

NODE.JS Server Side Code

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
var config = require('./config.js');
var num_processes = 1;//require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    // This stores our workers. We need to keep them to be able to reference
    // them based on source IP address. It's also useful for auto-restart,
    // for example.
    var workers = [];

    // Helper function for spawning worker at index 'i'.
    var spawn = function (i) {
        workers[i] = cluster.fork();

        // Optional: Restart worker on exit
        workers[i].on('exit', function (worker, code, signal) {
            if (config.server.restart_instances_on_crash) {
                spawn(i);
                logging.log('debug', 'Node instances exited, respawning...');
            }
        });
    };

    // Spawn workers.
    for (var i = 0; i < num_processes; i++) {
        spawn(i);
    }

    // Helper function for getting a worker index based on IP address.

    var worker_index = function (ip, len) {
        var s = '';
        for (var i = 0, _len = ip.length; i < _len; i++) {
            if (ip[i] !== '.') {
                s += ip[i];
            }
        }

        return Number(s) % len;
    };

    /* wait 5 seconds to make sure all the instances are running and initialized */

    setTimeout(function () {
        // Create the outside facing server listening on our port.

        var options = {
            pauseOnConnect: true
        };
        var server = net.createServer(options, function (connection) {
            // We received a connection and need to pass it to the appropriate
            // worker. Get the worker for this connection's source IP and pass
            // it the connection.
            var str = connection.remoteAddress;
            var ip = str.replace("::ffff:", '');
            var worker = workers[worker_index(ip, num_processes)];
            worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
        }).listen(config.server.listenport);
        logging.log('debug', 'Server listening on ' + config.server.listenip + ':' + config.server.listenport + '...');

    }, 5000);
    process.on('uncaughtException', function (error) {
        logging.log('error', 'uncaughtException');
        logging.log('error',error.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });

} else {
    var express = require('express');
    var sio = require('socket.io');
    var sio_redis = require('socket.io-redis');

    var dateandtime = require('./includes/dateandtime.js');
    var stats = require('./includes/stats.js');
    var helper = require('./includes/helper.js');

    // Note we don't use a port here because the master listens on it for us.
    var app = new express();

    // Don't expose our internal server to the outside.
    var server = app.listen(0, 'localhost'),
        io = sio(server);
    io.set('origins', '*:*');

}
```

In my Client side i have following code based socket.io JS module. (All these works fine without the SSL connection when using net module only)

Following is the client side javascript code to connect to the node server using socket.io functions.

```
var root_url = 'http://'+window.location.hostname;
var socket_io = 'http://example.com/js/chat/socket.io-1.3.5.js';
$(document).ready(function () { 
$.getScript(socket_io, function () {
        socket = io.connect(root_url + ':8440');
... etc
```

Comment: I see a number of potential issues here. Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Yes. Long time ago

Answer (score 0):

Can only hint you into checking the cors package for crossdomain requests but the deeper issue could be that not everything is running in SSL. (mixed http & https)

Comment: can i create a ssl connection with require 'net' ? as far as i am concern i need https or tls, but both dont have the same behaviour as above or do they ?